# Is a map backwards compatible with a repeated keyvaluepair?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Am I able to use

```proto
message Foo {
  map<string, string> foo = 1;
}
```

in place of

```proto
message Foo {
  repeated KeyValuePair foo = 1;
}

message KeyValuePair {
  string key = 1;
  string value = 2;
}
```

?

The first source is in proto3 and the second is in proto2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't have duplicate keys, they will be very similar. If you have duplicate keys, using a map will have different behaviour, as duplicatws will either cause overwrites or an exception (I can't recall which, sorry). Also, "repeated" is usually implemented as a list/array/etc, so: order is retained. "map" is usually implemented with some kind of map/dictionary structure, where order is **not** usually guaranteed.

So: if order doesn't matter and you always have unique keys: you're fine.

Comment: So if I'm a client using the proto3 version talking to a server using the proto2 version and I send over a map, I'll be fine?

Comment: @Soren they are wire compatible, so yes *as long as* the 2 caveats I mentioned aren't issues. BTW, I though "map" had been pushed down into proto2 now, anyway. But the behaviour is what matters, and that is: as above